# Generate Sl No on the Form on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with three input fields named `sl no` ,`stationerytype` and `stationeryqty` There is a symbol `+` and `-` to append or delete these three field on click. I am trying the sl no field to generate Sl no automatically when i click the plus symbol and if I click - it will automatically adjust the sl no. but My sl no field remains blank .my code is

```
<table   class="table table-bordered" id="tb" >
<tr class="tr-header">

<th class= "col-md-1" align="centre">Sl.No.</th>
<th class= "col-md-6" align="centre">STATIONARY TYPE</th>
<th class= "col-md-4" align="centre">STATIONARY QUANTITY</th>
<th class= "col-md-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Stationery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>

</tr>
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
{   
?>

<td><input type="text" style="text-decoration: none" name="slno" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>"  ></td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-decoration: none" name="stationerytype"  ></td>
<td><input type="number" name="stationeryqtyrecd" id="stationeryqtyrecd" min="0"></td>

<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
<?php  }?>
</table>

<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" >ADD </button>   

<script>
var max = 4;
var count = 1;
$(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            if(count <= max ){
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              data.find("input").val('');
              count++;
            }else{
             alert("Sorry!! Can't add more than five samples at a time !!");
           }
              
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>1) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
}); 
 
</script>
                            </div>
```

Thanks for any suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `addMore` function after erasing data from the newly created row just add one more line to set the serial number in first `td`.

```
$('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            if(count <= max ){
              var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
              debugger;
              data.find("input").val('');
              //set the count value in first td
              data.find("input")[0].value = ++count;
              
            }else{
             alert("Sorry!! Can't add more than five samples at a time !!");
           }
              
     });
```

working javascript [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecw43ym8/) example

Comment: while appending it is showing the sl no but if there are 5 row and i remove a row in between the sl no remains same.it wont adjust according to no.

Comment: for that we need to check and adjust serial number in delete function.

Comment: I am new to this can u help me to achieve this .

Comment: i have updated the fiddle link please check there the logic in delete function.